# instanceof operator does not behave consistently

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, virtual-machine, instanceof

I've been handed Java code with two interfaces

```
interface ISuper {}
interface ISub extends ISuper {}
```

and two classes that implement them

```
class ParentClass implements ISuper {}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass implements ISub {}
```

Within the code is

```
ParentClass myVariable = <properly defined ParentClass object>

if(! (myVariable instanceof ISub)) {
    <throw an error that breaks the code>
}
```

Just from reading this, it seems like the check `(myVariable instanceof ISub)` should always return `false`, since `ParentClass` does not implement `ISub`, so the code should always break.  So, it seems like the author expected that `myVariable` *would* be recognized as an instance of `ISub`.

And in fact, **this code does execute properly on some machines!**  In particular, it fails to break on one running under

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

However, it does break as expected on my local machine, with

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I did a little local testing with some toy code and found

```
myVariable instanceof ParentClass  ->  true
myVariable instanceof ISuper       ->  true
myVariable instanceof ChildClass   ->  false
myVariable instanceof ISub         ->  false
```

all as expected.

Can anyone deduce what the original author intended?  Are there scenarios I'm not aware of where this use of `instanceof` ought to work?

Comment: `ParentClass myVariable = new ChildClass()` is valid and would be an example where the test would pass. So it is essential to know what exactly is written where you put `<properly defined ParentClass object>`. But you're right that given the same code, it should act the same on all JRE's.

Comment: if you assign myVariable = new ParentClass(); the condition would be true because you negate it (false) with "!". Regardless the outcome should be the same on all JVMs.

Comment: @geert3 i don't think he wants to assign new ChildClass()... but i might be wrong.. see my comment before

Comment: @progressive_overload the condition is indeed true in that case, so the program will throw an exception, which is expected behavior. Question is rather why would it skip the `if` (i.e. why the entire condition would be false in some cases).

Comment: @geert3 but it is expected that myVariable is not an instance of ISub so why the error handling then?

Comment: @progressive_overload IMHO you are right that myVariable instance of IStub is expected to evaluate to false. So it is a good question why a negotiation operator is put in front of the condition. Nevertheless it seems to be the better question why the behaviour of the Open JDK JRE is wrong

Comment: Have you used the same code, that behaves differently under OpenJDK? Can you post the test you have used and what exactly failed.

Comment: Are `ParentClass` and `ISuper` given classes that can't be modified or so? Might be an attempt to ensure that some code somewhere deep down uses the "extended" version even though you can not guarantee it properly via method signatures.

Comment: @geert3 You're right that `<properly defined ParentClass object>` is a big assumption here.  According the documentation, however, the method that provides `myVariable` returns a `ParentClass` object, not `ChildClass`.  You've made me suspect that someone has changed the package to allow the method to return `ChildClass` without updating the documentation.

Comment: It is not clear if your test code fails on that machine or something else.

Comment: @tak3shi I have limited access to the remote machine (the one that works), so I haven't tried the toy code.  I can try later today, though.